# Excel 2010: Blank pasted cells require activation causing formula issues

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, copy-paste

I'm having a problem copy/pasting from one Excel file to another.

I have a workbook with forms for entering data. Recently, I added a sub to auto-capitalize the entry cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '   Code goes in the Worksheet specific module
    Dim rng As Range
        '   Set Target Range, i.e. Range("A1, B2, C3"), or Range("A1:B3")
        Set rng = Target.Parent.Range("B11:C47")
             '   Only look at single cell changes
            If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            '   Only look at that range
            If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            '   Action if Condition(s) are met (do your thing here...)
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Value = UCase(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Target.Value, " ", ""))
            Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Now when I copy and paste a range of cells (Ex: B2:B12) that have empty cells intermixed to an older version of the same file *without* the sub, some of the empty cells are causing formula issues. This goes away if the blank pasted cells are activated (double clicked in or deleted).

I do not have a way to modify the older version of the file as it has been distributed to multiple people and would be impossible to correct all of them.

This seems to happen randomly as it is not all empty cells that cause the issue and it is not always the same cells. I have tried =CODE(), =VALUE(), =ISTEXT(), =ISNUMBER() to find what is actually in the cell, but I can't get any value, just that the cell is text (as all the entry cells are formatted as text).

To try and answer any questions that may arise:

- Copy/pasting just values, etc... results in the same issue
- Copy/pasting within each file works with no issue
- Going from the old file to the new file works

Short of just going in and "deleting" the "values" from all the "empty" cells each time, is there a way to prevent these empty pasted cells from coming up as needing to be activated in the old file? I'm assuming the issue arises from the sub as this problem wasn't there in previous versions of this file.

**EDIT**
All the code for one of the sheets in question:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As     Boolean)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'   Code goes in the Worksheet specific module
Dim rng As Range
    '   Set Target Range, i.e. Range("A1, B2, C3"), or Range("A1:B3")
    Set rng = Target.Parent.Range("B11:C47")
         '   Only look at single cell changes
        If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        '   Only look at that range
        If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        '   Action if Condition(s) are met (do your thing here...)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = UCase(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Target.Value, " ", ""))
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableAfterValueChange(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal TargetRange As Range)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableBeforeAllocateChanges(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal ValueChangeStart As Long, ByVal ValueChangeEnd As Long, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableBeforeCommitChanges(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal ValueChangeStart As Long, ByVal ValueChangeEnd As Long, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal ValueChangeStart As Long, ByVal ValueChangeEnd As Long)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableChangeSync(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Comment: How about pressing `F9` directly after pasting?

Comment: Please post the rest of your code. The code you posted does nothing to empty values and cannot be the source of the problem.

Comment: I tried F9 after pasting, no change unfortunately...

Comment: I unfortunately can't post the rest of the code, there are over 50 sheets with multiple macros and a total file size of over 3.5 MB. This sub was the only change in the code when the issue presented, which leads me to believe that it is the cause of the problem...  

I should mention that the "empty" cells show a count when highlighted. They only show up AFTER something has been entered and the sub runs. Could the sub be leaving cells with either a ghost value or activation requirement when it ends? Thanks

Comment: I should add that having the function =ISBLANK() looking at the problem column does indicate whether the cell contains a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the newer file, but not the sub. Someone else (shared master file) had apparently left data in a few of the cells. I'm not sure why this didn't cause an error on the sheet it was on but did after being copied over to the older file. The data wasn't a space or 0 that wasn't displayed so the formulas didn't know how to deal with it and returned errors. Clearing the contents of the cells on the newer file and saving corrected the issue.